# Research Experience in PhD Proposal

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science, united-kingdom, research-proposal

I am applying to a (UK) PhD programme in theoretical computer science/maths and I am currently writing a rather technical research proposal.

I have experience working on (very) closely related projects. However, I am not sure whether to mention it in my research proposal to emphasise I have the relevant experience or mention it in my SOP since they are related to the technical points that are only mentioned in the proposal.

What should I do in this situation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Any research experience is helpful when applying to a graduate program.  Generally I would definitely mention this experience in my SOP, as it is useful for showing that you have research experience (even better if it is related in some way).

A research *proposal* is for the research that you *intend* to conduct once you have begun your graduate studies.  Mentioning your prior experience here would therefore be more dependent on how closely related your prior research is to your future research and how it could *support* such work going forward.